# Can I specify which HID my C++ program listens to

Tags: c++, windows-7, hid, rfid

I am trying to create an application that reads keyboard input from a HID. The OS I am trying to acheive this on is Windows 7. In what way would I specify to my program that it needs to listen to just one HID device (I have a normal keyboard, and an RFID reader as my two devices) Could some one tell me the best route to take if I wanted to just listen to one HID and ignore other keystrokes (From the keyboard)

Comment: And your operating system is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register for HID input with `RegisterRawInputDevices()` ? Because in that case, you tell Windows for which devices you want "raw" input.

[edit]
Rough sketch:

```
int count = 0;
GetRawInputDeviceList(0, &count, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE);
std::vector<RAWINPUTDEVICE> devs(count);
GetRawInputDeviceList(&devs[0], &count, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE);
// Select device(s) you want
RegisterRawInputDevices(&devs[0], &count, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE);
```

Comment: Could I have a mini example of how to use this function. Its three parameters

Answer (score 1):

You should probably handle the `WM_INPUT` message and check `hDevice` in the `lParam` input structure. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645590%28v=VS.85%29.aspx